# Uploading file to a web server in QT

Tags: qt, http, file-upload, ftp, webserver

I need to upload a file using ftp or http. I checked downloading from servers like ftp.qt.nokia.com. where download was successful[even though the file(s) downloaded was broken but with almost same size as on Web server]. I tried to upload a file to servers like qt.nokia.com,ftp.trolltech.com. Doing so When I used http, I got an html doc as a response with error count 0,but error string as unkown error. When I used ftp, connection was established, logged in but didn't close connection and again error string unkown error. My point is how can I know that whether my file is uploaded to a server successfully? Can I check it on my own system by setting up a server(for ex: Apache Tomcat server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up a local FTP or HTTP server, you should not rely on any server you don't have full control over. A virtual machine is the probably the most hassle-free solution.